# Display only one distinct column for multiple common rows in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Datatable with the following format

```
srikanth 1200 Watch   
srikanth 1300 Bag   
srikanth 1400 Shirt
```

I want my report in following format

```
srikanth 1200 Watch
         1300 Bag
         1400 Shirt
```

Basically, I want to trim the repeating column. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to group by the first column, right click the group heading and select 'section expert'.
In here you can set the section to 'Underlay following sections' which will drop down the group header to the first row.

From:

```
srikanth
         1200 Watch   
         1300 Bag   
         1400 Shirt
```

To:

```
srikanth 1200 Watch   
         1300 Bag   
         1400 Shirt
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the report is sorted by the first column, then right-click on the column field in your report -> "Format Field" -> "Common" tab -> Check the "Suppress If Duplicated" checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Insert Menu--->Group option,in that select the first column(In this example Srikanth).After Grouping,then right click on group heading and select 'Format Section'. Here you check  'Underlay following sections' option,then click on OK.

From:

srikanth
         1200 Watch
         1300 Bag      ------>After Grouping
         1400 Shirt
To:

srikanth 1200 Watch
         1300 Bag      ------>after formated
         1400 Shirt